# Instagram API does not retrieve followers count

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this code to retrieve Followers from a Instagram user:

```
function instagram(){
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    type: 'GET',
    data: {
      access_token: settings.instagram_token
    },
    success: function(data) {
      var followers = parseInt(data.data.counts.followed_by);
      var k = kFormatter(followers);
      jQuery('#wrapper .item.instagram .count').append(k);
      jQuery('#wrapper .item.instagram').attr('href','https://instagram.com/'+settings.instagram_user);
      getTotal(followers); 
    }
  });
}

(jQuery)); jQuery('#wrapper').SocialCounter({
    //Get Usernames
    facebook_user: 'abc',
    instagram_user: 'abc',
    youtube_user: 'abc',
 twitch_username:'abc',
    //Get Access Tokens,keys,client_ids
    instagram_token:'0000000000.1677ed0.19659eaa5e654ae6afc5cce1bf9a6522',
    facebook_token:'abc',
    youtube_key:'abc',
   twitch_client_id:'abc',
  });
```

Also, my app is in sandbox mode but i don't know if it needs to be live to get it working. However the result of this function is 0

Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

From their website it sounds like sandbox mode shouldn't prevent you from getting the correct data. This question shows someone grabbing follower counts in Javascript: [Getting other account's followers count by using Instagram API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43989516/getting-other-accounts-followers-count-by-using-instagram-api)

Also, if that's a real API token you should definitely remove that when you post code online.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're accessing the result incorrectly. This will hopefully solve your problem:

```
var token = '0000000000.1677ed0.19659eaa5e654ae6afc5cce1bf9a6522';

$.ajax({
  url: 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self',
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  type: 'GET',
  data: {access_token: token},
  success: function(data){
    var follows = data['data']['counts']['follows'];
    $(".instagram").text(follows);
  },
  error: function(data){
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

Comment: I'm using this code: https://github.com/juanv911/SocialCounters
Actually i don't know where to put the code to get him working.

Comment: Also, i need to retrieve followers of another account that is not the owner of the access token